# v2: android update lib-project required for ant build?

Tags: android, ant, maps

I successfully upgraded my app to use Android Google Maps V2 rather than V1, building all the while with Eclipse. When I turned to getting the ant build to work, I immediately discovered that ant wants to build the google-play-services_lib library project, but the distribution of the project from Google doesn't include a build.xml file.

After a bit of research, I decided that I needed to run "android update lib-project" on the project as delivered from Google to generate the build.xml file. I did that, and now the ant build works.

This, however, is a bit of a pain, because it either means that I have to check the library project into source control so the rest of the team can build, or require everybody to obtain it themselves and also do the "android update lib-project". Either way, the project has to be maintained over time to get any updates Google may release.

Is this sort of solution really the only way to deal with this issue?

Thanks,

Mark Peters

Comment: Thanks...was doing all sorts of weird stuff like copying the play lib's res and lib files into my project before building w/o luck.
I'd recommend filing a bug on the google-play-services project.  I'll star it if you do and I suspect a lot of other people will as well :-)

Seems like Google internally is moving to Gradle and forgetting about Ant.  It's too bad they did that without everything in place first or at least making the libraries backwards compatible :-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this sort of solution really the only way to deal with this issue?

Well, you can file an issue on [the Maps V2 issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list) to get them to ship command-line-build project files. Or, if you're a Maven user, you can see if/when the Maven+Android community Mavenizes the Google Play Services library, if they haven't done so already.

However, at the end of the day, command-line builds require corresponding build files. Similarly, Eclipse users have to import the library project into Eclipse -- it does not magically get put there by IDE gnomes (the lazy bums!).

Comment: I guess I expected that releasing a library in a form that will build without an IDE was so obviously important that not doing that meant there must be some trick I didn't know about. ;-)