# Android Ant build causes runtime ClassNotFoundException when Eclipse build does not

Tags: android, ant

I've been trying to get a command line build working for my Android project so the build can be automated in Jenkins, however, the Ant build causes a runtime `ClassNotFoundException` error despite my Eclipse build not having any issues.

I'm wondering what is causing the discrepancy. I noticed the path doesn't appear to be correct, so that might be where to start.

LogCat

```
W/dalvikvm( 1243): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1243): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

E/AndroidRuntime( 1243): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{gov.va.fbb.android/gov.va.fbb.android.activities.StartupActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "gov.va.fbb.android.activities.StartupActivity" on path: /system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/gov.va.fbb.android-1.apk

E/AndroidRuntime( 1243): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1243): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1243): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1243): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1243): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1243): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1243): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1243): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1243): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1243): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1243): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1243): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1243): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "gov.va.fbb.android.activities.StartupActivity" on path: /system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/gov.va.fbb.android-1.apk

E/AndroidRuntime( 1243): at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1243): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1243): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1243): at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1243): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)

E/AndroidRuntime( 1243): ... 11 more

W/ActivityManager( 297): Force finishing activity gov.va.fbb.android/.activities.StartupActivity

W/WindowManager( 297): Failure taking screenshot for (123x205) to layer 21010
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and found this link below:

[v2: android update lib-project required for ant build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149440/v2-android-update-lib-project-required-for-ant-build)

My project had google-play-services, action bar Sherlock, and number of other projects being referenced from my original project.  To link it properly I had to run android update lib-project -p . from each project directory and not android update project -p . .  I only needed to run android update project -p . from my original project.